# Create Fill-In-The-Blanks Text From Text Chunks using Regex and Replace

Tags: regex

I trying to create a fill-in-the-blanks worksheet from a chunk of text, and I think regex and a replace function in a text editor will greatly expedite my project.

Example text:

> HAMLET  O, that this too too solid flesh would melt Thaw and resolve
>   itself into a dew! Or that the Everlasting had not fix'd His canon
>   'gainst self-slaughter! O God! God! How weary, stale, flat and
>   unprofitable, Seem to me all the uses of this world! Fie on't! ah fie!
>   'tis an unweeded garden, That grows to seed; things rank and gross in
>   nature Possess it merely. That it should come to this! But two months
>   dead: nay, not so much, not two: So excellent a king; that was, to
>   this, Hyperion to a satyr; so loving to my mother That he might not
>   beteem the winds of heaven Visit her face too roughly. Heaven and
>   earth! Must I remember? why, she would hang on him, As if increase of
>   appetite had grown By what it fed on: and yet, within a month-- Let me
>   not think on't--Frailty, thy name is woman!-- A little month, or ere
>   those shoes were old With which she follow'd my poor father's body,
>   Like Niobe, all tears:--why she, even she-- O, God! a beast, that
>   wants discourse of reason, Would have mourn'd longer--married with my
>   uncle, My father's brother, but no more like my father Than I to
>   Hercules: within a month: Ere yet the salt of most unrighteous tears
>   Had left the flushing in her galled eyes, She married. O, most wicked
>   speed, to post With such dexterity to incestuous sheets! It is not nor
>   it cannot come to good: But break, my heart; for I must hold my
>   tongue.

Replace alternate text sets with a blank "*_*_" a character length equal to that of the length that has been replaced, where a text set is defined as group of words ending with a "!", "," "--", "?" etc.

So the above text from Hamlet becomes like

> HAMLET O, ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*** Or that the
>   Everlasting had not fix'd His canon 'gainst self-slaughter! ***_*_**
>   God! ***_*__*_*_**, stale, ***_*__*_*__*_*_** ......

What is the regex that I should use to achieve this end?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? And what language are you using?

Comment: Could you be more explicit on how original text is tranformed?

Comment: In which language/tool do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt using `perl` regex:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?)([\!\?\,;\.]|--)(.*?)([\!\?\,;\.]|--)/\1\2________________\4/g' file
```

Output:

> HAMLET O,***_*__*_*___**! Or that the Everlasting had not fix'd His
>   canon 'gainst self-slaughter!**__*_*__*_*_**! God!***_*__*_*___**,
>   stale,**__*_*__*_*_**, Seem to me all the uses of this
>   world!***_*__*_*___**! ah fie!**__*_*__*_*_**, That grows to
>   seed;***_*__*_*___**. That it should come to this!**__*_*__*_*_**,
>   not so much,***_*__*_*___**; that was,**__*_*__*_*_**, Hyperion to a
>   satyr;***_*__*_*___**. Heaven and earth!**__*_*__*_*_**?
>   why,***_*__*_*___**, As if increase of appetite had grown By what it
>   fed on: and yet,**__*_*__*_*_**-- Let me not think
>   on't--***_*__*_*___**, thy name is woman!**__*_*__*_*_**-- A little
>   month,***_*__*_*___**, Like Niobe,**__*_*__*_*_**--why
>   she,***_*__*_*___**-- O,**__*_*__*_*_**! a beast,***_*__*_*___**,
>   Would have mourn'd longer--**__*_*__*_*_**, My father's
>   brother,***_*__*_*___**, She married.**__*_*__*_*_**, most wicked
>   speed,***_*__*_*___**! It is not nor it cannot come to good: But
>   break,**__*_*__*_*_**; for I must hold my tongue.

This solution replaces fix number of '__' and I am yet to figure out how to replace with matching charater length.